# Why isn't Python throwing an overflow error?

Tags: python, overflow

I'm learning Python and I have a question about the range of the data types.

This program:

```
print("8 bits:", pow(2, 8)-1)
print("16 bits:", pow(2, 16)-1)
print("32 bits:", pow(2, 32)-1)
print("64 bits:", pow(2, 64)-1)

print( pow(18446744073709551615+18446744073709551615+2, 9) )
```

Produces the following output:

```
8 bits: 255
16 bits: 65535
32 bits: 4294967295
64 bits: 18446744073709551615
12663316555422952143897729076205936129798725073982046203600028471956337925454431
59912019973433564390346740077701202633417478988975650566195033836314121693019733
02667340133957632
```

My question is: how can Python calculate the result of the last call to `pow()`? My CPU cannot handle integers with more than 64 bits, so I expect the operation to produce an overflow.

Comment: Just drop `print` in `print( pow(`

Comment: Um, what is your question?

Comment: Python integers handle arbitrary large numbers. It is not limited by 64 bit integers.

Answer (score 3):

The Python long integer type is only limited by your available memory. Until you run out of memory, the digits will just keep on coming.

Quoting from the [numeric types documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#numeric-types-int-float-long-complex):

> Long integers have unlimited precision.

Python will transparently use long integers when you need the unlimited precision. In Python 3, all integers are long integers; there is no distinction.

Answer (score 2):

Python knows two data types for integers: `int` and `long`.  If a number is too large for an `int` (64 bit), then automatically a `long` is used.  Also if the result of a computation is too large for an `int`, a `long` is used instead.

You can explicitly declare a literal to be a long; just add an `L` to it (an `l` also is possible but is discouraged because in many fonts this is indistinguishable or at least very much alike a `1` (one) character).  So, `5L` is a `long`.

Typically this distinction is not important; to know of the difference will become necessary, though, if you compare the types of values (because `type(5)` ≠ `type(5L)`).

`long`s aren't limited in any particular number of bits.  At ridiculous high values, the memory consumption and the computation times pose a practical limit, though.

Also keep in mind that computing stuff with these `long` might be faster than `print`ing them because when converting them to a string for the printing, they have to be converted into the decimal system.

Comment: In Python 2, switching between the two types is entirely transparent *anyway*; only C extensions needed to care about the difference, as well as when you were using anything limited to `sys.maxsize` (lists, tuples, and `range()` and `xrange()`).

Comment: In any case, you are only muddying the waters here; *this is not a question about `long` vs. `int`*.

Comment: The OP contains `print` as a statement.  I assumed Python 2 because of this.  How come you think it's Python 3?

Comment: Ah, of course, `str(1L)`  is still `1`; my mistake.

Comment: I stumbled over the difference between `int` and `long` when I compared types of values once, so this knowledge might be useful.  But as I said, "Typically this distinction is not important".